# How to implement CI/CD for Nuxt 3 project with GitHub Actions and CPanel?

Tags: github, deployment, cpanel, nuxtjs3

My project is built with Nuxt 3 and I want to deploy the static files generated in the dist folder to a shared hosting server that uses CPanel. I also want to automate the deployment process with GitHub Actions, so that every time I push changes to my GitHub repository, the files are uploaded to the server. However, I am not sure how to configure the workflow file for GitHub Actions and the settings for CPanel to make this work for Nuxt 3.